# A question on prime sequence

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $\{P_n\}, n\in \mathbb{N}$ be the sequence prime numbers such that $P_1=2, P_2=3\dots$.

Define a new sequence $\{S_n\}$ such that $S_n=P_n+2$ $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Now the question is: For every prime $p$, does there exist an $N\in  \mathbb{N}$, such that $p|S_N$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is whether for all $p$ there is a prime $q$ with $q\equiv -2\pmod p$. When $p$ is odd, this is a special case of Dirichlet's
theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions.

Comment: ... and when $p$ is even it's obviously false.

Comment: @RobertIsrael $q=2$...